# How to Sort array values based on Edit Text input characters?

Tags: java, android, spinner, arrays

I am having an array of String which is being used to show in a spinner.
Now my need is

> When the user giving their input in the edit text have to sort the array based on the edit text values ans have to show it in the spinner. I cannot get the logic fully.

I have tried like this.,

```
String[] a1 = { "Android", "Apple", "Andrew", "Ball" }, a2 = null;
EditText mn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.plus);

            a2 = a1;
    mn.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
                            Arrays.sort(a1);
            doCall();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }
    });

}

protected void doCall() {

    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        String s = a1[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < mn.getText().toString().length(); j++) {

            if (Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(j)) == Character
                    .toLowerCase(mn.getText().toString().charAt(j))) {
                if (j == mn.getText().toString().length() - 1) {
                    String temp = a1[0];
                    a1[0] = a2[i];
                    a1[i] = temp;

                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IF i am giving "a" means i am getting "Andrew,Ball,Apple,Android"
 but What i need to be shown is "Andrew,Android,Apple,Ball" How can i achieve this. thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try call `Arrays.sort(names)` before end of `doCall()` and then notify yours Spinner Adapter.

Comment: I have updated but now too it is now showing the correct result. isn't my logic in doCall is correct?

Comment: thanks a lot. it is working now. me only made the mistake. thanks

Answer (score 0):

## AutoComplete ##

Try using the autoComplete functionality:

```
 public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.countries);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
     AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
             findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
     textView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

 private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
     "Android", "Apple", "Andrew", "Ball"
 };
}
```

Comment: Yes i can use this but the need is like this that s y i am doing like this..I cannot give u upvote now i dont have reputation that much. i will upvote u when i got the reputation.. thanks